# Limit connection in RESTful web service

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

Is there a way to configure a rest web service to allow only one connection at a time?

I am using Wildfly 9.0.1-Final with the resteasy 3.0.11.Final implementation.

Comment: Can I know, why you need this?

Comment: want to force a client to finish his connection before he starts a new call

Comment: how previous running call is affecting new call? you want same client to have only one connection at a time?

Comment: I want to ensure a sequential behaviour. The client has to receive the answer of the previous call before he can start a new call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronized block on static field:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

@GET
@Path("find")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response find(){
     synchronized(LOCK){
          //your code
     }
}
```

Comment: How you will release the lock now? as its static final.. There would only be one copy of each class variable per class, regardless of how many objects are created from it..

Comment: May be I am wrong, but as I can understand @Manuel wants single active connection/request per time. Actually it is strange requirement, and most likely it is bad idea.  Lock is released after execution `find` method. After this it is ready to perform next request.

Comment: Exactly.. its client sever architecture.. it made of supporting multiple clients at a time. Removing its core functionality not a good idea

Comment: static block inside the method doesn't work as the connection starts to live earlier respectively lives longer than the method is active.

I also don't think that it is such a strange requirement. I believe there is a configuration for the amount of allowed open connections. Otherwise a server would risk to starve. And I just want to set it to one :)

Comment: It is part of configuration Java EE server. Usually Java EE server can limit connections count, but not for REST framework inside one application, but also for all applications at once.

Comment: You can use external tools on OS level

Comment: @sibnick do you know where to set this config and is it maybe possible to restrict to one connection per client?

Comment: I suggest nginx as proxy server. You can use modules: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html or http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html

Comment: @sibnick actually I meant the configuration file / parameter in the application server

Comment: I think it is not possible currently. You can set max-concurrent-requests  http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/configuration/filter/connection-limit/index.html ,  but it affects all applications